# Can I use the Axe weapon more than once?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Once I find the Axe card, can I continue using it to "solve" all locked puzzles I find or is this a one time use then discard card?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it multiple times to pass any **Lock Puzzle** as long as you can pass the test of strength.

Note that the Axe cannot be used on Rune or Wiring puzzles.  (We played this wrong for several games before figuring it out!)